# Python Sqlite Concurrent access

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, concurrency, sqlite

I have a scenario where a third party application scans a folder and triggers my python script/generated EXE for the number of times (yes! number of separate processes) for the number of files that are in the folder. 
My script/application writes the path of the file to a local sqlite database, calls the next application and exits. 
My script/application takes care that it calls only one instance of the next application. But nothing can be done of the third party application that calls my script.

The ISSUE
Sometimes more than 1000 instances of my script/application can be called at the same time resulting in almost 1000 concurrent connections to the local sqlite database. 
Due to the limited number of concurrent connections possible with sqlite, some of the processes are getting a "database is locked" Exception. This results in some of the file names NOT being written to the database
We came up with a work around for this. We write in the database in an infinite loop. On encountering the exception, we make the thread sleep for say 50 milliseconds and try again till such time that the write works. I know that this is not a clean approach.

Is there a better way of doing this? How do I handle 1000 may be 10000 or may be more concurrent connections and yet each script succeeds?

Comment: Why are you using sqlite for this kind of application?

Comment: You could use the Write Ahead Log perhaps (your specification is a bit unbounded) or set a new timeout if the database is locked, but it seems (at least to me) that this is not the correct technology to use.

Comment: If I _had_ to use sqlite I'd probably go down the path of a single writer process reading from a kafka feed, but I have no idea how successful that would be.

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround is correct, but you can make the database do most of the work by setting a [busy timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout). (For 1000 connections, this needs to be set extremely high, essentially inifinite, like you're already doing.)

But this still results in *random* wait times.
SQLite does not wait until one writer's transaction has finished and then signals the next, because there is no *portable* API for this. However, in Windows, you could use a named [mutex object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266.aspx) (which requires some [trickery](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577794-win32-named-mutex-class-for-system-wide-mutex/) to access it from Python).

Comment: Genuine question; you're very knowledgeable in SQLite, would you personally go down the route before switching technology (if SQLite wasn't the forced option)?

Comment: I'm currently at a point where I need to decide whether I should move out of SQLite with a much lower load than this and you've presented this as a logical course of action to get over a couple of hurdles, but I'm not sure I'm comfortable with it.

Comment: @roganjosh Client/server databases like PostgreSQL try to increase concurrency by allowing multiple writers to modify different parts of the database. I don't know if 1000 connections appending to the same table would even work (if the database can prove that they don't interfere with each other, it might work just fine), but this problem is more about finding a cheap mechanism to serialize all the writers.